# No Hyper-V manager in start menu

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-11

I've enabled Hypervisor platform and Virtual Machine Platform in optional Windows Features
([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFM79.png)), I've enabled hardware virtualisation in the BIOS, but I can't see the Hyper-V manager in the start menu. I'm running Windows 11 and i'm able to start WSL somehow (so virtualisation is possible), but not access the Hyper-V manager.

Comment: Hyper-V is Hyper-V, which is not officially available in Windows Home. There's some unofficial way to get it installed though.

Comment: If it's not available in home, why is it possible to enable in the Optional features menu?

Comment: Virtual Machine Platform isn’t Hyper-V.  It’s a base component that is required for WSL2 to run under Windows Home.  Hyper-V, the Virtual Machine Manager, requires Windows Pro or Server.

Comment: @stickynotememo - per your screenshot your not actually able to enable Hyper-V. Hyper-V isn’t and has never been required to install WSL2. Hardware virtualization is required but not Hyper-V

Comment: The WSL2 mention was just to prove i had virtualisation turned on, my question is about Hyper-V and not about WSL.